# Rails conditional joins and merge method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, merge

I'm trying to build my search query. My search form has two fields **tags** and **category**

My query currently looks like this

```
Video.joins(:tags, :categories).merge(Tag.where(:id => params[:tags])).merge(Category.where(:id => params[:category])).pluck(:id)
```

but sometimes user don't use category or tag and in that case my query is not working.

How can I put conditions so the query would merge only available attributes?

current code

```
    if params.has_key?(:category) && params.has_key?(:tags)
        @videos = RedtubeVideo.joins(:redtube_tags, :redtube_categories).merge(RedtubeTag.where(:id => params[:tags])).merge(RedtubeCategory.where(:id => params[:category])).pluck(:id)
    elsif params.has_key?(:category)
        @videos = RedtubeVideo.joins(:redtube_categories).merge(RedtubeCategory.where(:id => params[:category])).pluck(:id)
    elsif params.has_key?(:tags)
        @videos = RedtubeVideo.joins(:redtube_tags).merge(RedtubeTag.where(:id => params[:tags]))
    end
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit about this **How can I put conditions so the query would merge only available attributes?**

Comment: I added my current code, from which should be more clear what I'm trying achieve

Comment: You can put a ***default query*** in the `else` block if there is no `:category` or `:tags`